# How to create a trip calculator in Django?

Tags: django, beautifulsoup, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm working on a personal project. I need to add a trip calculator at the home page.

How can I create the calculator functionalities?

- I intend to use BeautifulSoup to grab the daily fuel price from a site in a separate file, import the function that prints  the fuel price into the calculator file and assign it to a variable to add it to the cost determining calculation.
- User will insert the fuel economy and approximate distance in text boxes.
- When user clicks on a ' calculate ' button, the total trip cost will appear in another text box or as a strong heading.
- I want to put the calculator inside a bootstrap class.
- Is a separate form for calculator be a better idea?
- How to show the result without refreshing the page and erasing all fields?

Comment: You seem to have described exactly how to create a trip calculator - what actually is stopping you from implementing this? (Whether or not the calculator should be on a separate form is a side issue for now)

Comment: How do I add all the user input values? Assign every value to a variable and then return the sum?

Comment: What do I need to do to show the result without loading the page and clearing the inputs?